# How do I prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})}=2\pi$

Tags: limits

I have to prove that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\sqrt{2-2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)}=2\pi
$$

It's geometrically obvious since it is the limit of the $n$-gons inside a unit circle.

But how do I prove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(f(\frac1n)-f(0))=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$

Answer (score 8):

From identity $\sin^2 \frac{t}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos t)$ we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{n\sqrt{2-2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)}} & = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{2n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \\
& = 2\pi\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{n}} \\
& = 2\pi\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{t} \\
& = 2\pi(1) \\
& = 2\pi
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

Hint: set $2\pi/n=2t$ and apply the bisection formula

Answer (score 5):

take $2$ outside, write, $1 - \cos 2(x) = 2 \sin^2(x)$ and take it outside of sqrt. then use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1/75151).

Answer (score 1):

Using power series:

$$\cos\frac{2\pi}n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(2\pi)^{2n}}{n^{2n}(2n)!}\implies 2-2\cos\frac{2\pi}n=2\left(\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)^2\frac12-\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)^2\frac1{24}+\ldots\right)$$

and from here

$$n\sqrt{2-2\cos\frac{2\pi}n}=n\sqrt{\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)^2+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}2\pi$$